# find function of a graph if we know x and y points

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to know how to find the function of a given values of a graph 
the known points are $$ (x,y)= 
(3.6,40) \quad \text{and} \quad 
(4.7,20) \quad\text{and}\quad
(7.3,5)
$$.Any reference how to solve this ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Hi PeterPi and welcome to Mathematics Stackexchange. I hope you realise that there are infinitely many functions that pass throug these points. Without further information, it's impossible to say which of those infinitely many functions it would be. Do you have any further information? Is it a polynomial, for example?

Comment: Understand, i was given the points basically and i need to find (x,y)=(3.6,40) then find (x,35) then (x,30) then (x,25) ... till (x,5) maybe this is a hint. But what type of function i dont know

Comment: would you have any context for this problem? Is it a school assignment or something more concrete? Because given the data, there is no single answer to the problem.

Comment: Basically the given problem is: i need to find the function that will determine how much a dog needs kcal if he runs certain amount of km per day.
Formula: (x* kg *km)  Only thing i know is that a heavy dog which is 40kg or above i need to put the value x=3.6 ,for a middle size dog which size is 20kg i need to put in x=4.7 and for small dogs i need to put 7.3
I need now to make the calculation more precise so to find 3.6 for 35 kg Dog .
Hope the problem makes sense a bit more now

Comment: So it's assumed that a $40$-kg dog uses LESS energy than a $20$-kg dog? Are you sure about that?

Comment: The x represents kilojoule So if a dog weights 40kg  and he runs 5 km the give formula would be:
(3.6kj * 40kg * 5) = 720kj so for 20kg dog would be (4.7kj * 20kg * 5) = 470kj and for small dog (7.3kj * 5kg * 5) = 182kj
So the big dog needs more energy but the x = 3.6 is increasing based on size of the dog.

Comment: Okay so the underlying assumption was that
$$
\text{energy used} = \text{constant} \cdot \text{dog mass} \cdot \text{distance}
$$
Next time, please write out this kinds of assumptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a complete guess with no real reasoning behind it, but I'm going to assume a relation like this:
$$
x(y) = \frac{1}{a+by} = \frac{1}{g(y)}
$$
with some constants $a$ and $b$. If I calculate the values of $g(y)$, I get the following pairs of points:
$$
\left(\frac{1}{x}, y \right) = (40, \frac{1}{3.6}); (20, \frac{1}{3.6}) \qquad \text{and} \qquad (5, \frac{1}{7.3}) 
$$
With linear regression I get approximately
$$
g(y) \approx 0.123 + \left(3.98\cdot 10^{-3}  \right)y
$$
and therefore the simplest way to approximate the function $x(y)$ would be
$$
x(y) \approx \frac{1}{0.123 + \left(3.98\cdot 10^{-3}  \right)y}
$$
This results in $x(5) \approx 7.0$, $x(20)\approx 4.94$ and $x(40) \approx 3.54$. It's not perfect, but it's an approximation. I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow i'm trying to understand everything but you made my life today a lot easier ,still will try hard to learn this .
Thanks !